# Email PHP Contact Form error as random output

Tags: php

**HTML**

```
<div id="formwrap">
    <form method="post" id="submitform" action="submitemail.php" >
        <input type="text" class="formstyle" title="Name" name="name" />
        <input type="text" class="formstyle" title="Email" name="email" />
        <textarea name="message" title="Message"></textarea>
        <input class="formstyletwo" type="submit" value="Send">  
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $mailto = "abcd@gmail.com"; /*PUT YOUR EMAIL IN HERE*/
    $cc = "";
    $bcc = "";
    $subject = "enquiry";
    $vname = "Website Contact Form";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    function validateEmail($email){
        if(eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$', $email)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 1  || strlen($_POST['message']) < 1 || validateEmail($email) == FALSE){
        if(empty($_POST['name'])){
            $emailerror .= '<li>Enter name</li>';
        }
        if(validateEmail($email) == FALSE){
            $emailerror .= '<li>Enter valid email</li>';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['message'])){
            $emailerror .= '<li>Enter message</li>';
        }
    }
    else{
        $emailerror .= "Your email has been sent successfully";
        // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY
        $timestamp = date("F j, Y, g:ia");
        $messageproper ="\n\n" .
            "Name: " .ucwords($_POST['name']) ."\n" .
            "Email: " .ucwords($email) ."\n" .
            "Comments: " .$_POST['message'] ."\n" .
            "\n\n" ;
            $messageproper = trim(stripslashes($messageproper));
            mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($_POST['first_name'])."\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );
    }
?>

<div id='emailerror'>
    <ul>
        <? echo $emailerror; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ON running it on XAMPP server, I am getting wrong output in the form of text just below send button

**ERROR OUTPUT DISPLAYED**

> Enter name'; } if(validateEmail($email) == FALSE) { $emailerror .= '
>   Enter valid email '; } if(empty($_POST['message'])) { $emailerror .= '
>   Enter message '; } } else { $emailerror .= "Your email has been sent
>   successfully"; // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY $timestamp = date("F j, Y,
>   g:ia"); $messageproper ="\n\n" . "Name: " . ucwords($_POST['name']) .
>   "\n" . "Email: " . ucwords($email) . "\n" . "Comments: " .
>   $_POST['message'] . "\n" . "\n\n" ; $messageproper =
>   trim(stripslashes($messageproper)); mail($mailto, $subject,
>   $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nReply-To:
>   \"".ucwords($_POST['first_name'])."\"
>   <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() ); } ?>

Comment: You shouldn't use shorthand tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this should work

```
<?php
$mailto = "abcd@gmail.com"; /*PUT YOUR EMAIL IN HERE*/
$cc = "";
$bcc = "";
$subject = "enquiry";
$vname = "Website Contact Form";


$errors = array();
if($_POST){

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name'] == "")
        $errors[] = "Please enter your name.";

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ""){
        if(!preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$%', $_POST['email']))
            $errors[] = "Not valid email";
    }else
        $errors[] = "Please enter your email";

    if(!isset($_POST['message']) || $_POST['message'] =="" ){
        $errors[] = "Please enter the message.";
    }

    if(!$errors){
        //send here your email...
        echo "email sended";
    }
}



?>
 <div id='emailerror'>
    <ul>
        <?php 
            foreach($errors as $err){
                echo "<li>$err</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: works cool..gives proper output. will implement the email part to make it work..thanks

Comment: I am glad to heard that, just run it from server the code coz from local it won't work also make sure that your host provider support SMTP otherwise from local you can use google gmail libraries for testing, its works prefect for me, refer to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using short tag for php `<? ?>` user `<?php ?>` it should fix it.

Also notice: from local you can not send emails throw mail function and the eregi function is Deprecated and instead of it use preg_match

```
preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$%', $email)
```

Comment: it removed all the error, but after clicking on send button, I am not getting any output

Comment: basically nothing happens on clicking on send button, no error message as "enter name" or anything

Answer (score 0):

Use full tags  as previously said. Also You should declare your $emailerror variable before you append to it like:

```
$emailerror = "";
```

at the beginning of your code.